# repackaging masonry for meteor gives error " ReferenceError: window is not defined "

Tags: javascript, meteor, masonry

I wish to add [desandro/masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) into my meteor project. But there was no meteor package that worked for me, so thought of creating one.

Here is package.js

```
'use strict';
 var packageName = 'masonryjs:masonry'; 
 Package.describe({
    name: packageName,
    summary: 'Masonryjs. cascading grid layout library',
    version: '1.1.0',
    git: 'https://github.com/desandro/masonry'
});
Package.onUse(function (api) {
    api.versionsFrom(['METEOR@0.9.0', 'METEOR@1.0']);
    api.export('masonry');
    api.addFiles([
        'masonry.pkgd.js',
        'export.js'
    ]);
});
```

export.js

```
masonry = this.masonry;
delete this.masonry;
```

The package is added, but when i run my meteor app i get this error

W20150121-21:50:29.788(5.5)? (STDERR) /home/nipun/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1d3bp9e++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20150121-21:50:29.788(5.5)? (STDERR)                       throw(ex);
W20150121-21:50:29.788(5.5)? (STDERR)                             ^
W20150121-21:50:29.824(5.5)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined
W20150121-21:50:29.824(5.5)? (STDERR)     at masonry (packages/masonryjs:masonry/masonry.pkgd.js:147:1)
W20150121-21:50:29.824(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /home/nipun/development/web/mason/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/masonryjs_masonry.js:2980:4
W20150121-21:50:29.824(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /home/nipun/development/web/mason/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/masonryjs_masonry.js:3008:3
W20150121-21:50:29.824(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /home/nipun/development/web/mason/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:205:10
W20150121-21:50:29.825(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150121-21:50:29.825(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/home/nipun/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1d3bp9e++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150121-21:50:29.825(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /home/nipun/development/web/mason/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:116:5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want this package to be used on the server where `window` is not available, then:

```
api.addFiles([ 'masonry.pkgd.js', 'export.js' ], 'client');
api.export('masonry', 'client');
```

Comment: also: 
api.addFiles([
        'masonry.pkgd.js',
        'export.js'
    ], 'client');